# Should this be 2 fragments or 2 activities?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a tabbed interface for my program - there are two tabs: take photo and view photos.

As the name suggests, the user can take a photo in "take photo" and the user can view photos taken in "view photos". Right now the way its set up I use one single MainActivity and I have TakePhotoFragment and ViewPhotoFragment -- question is: does this contradict the principles in which Fragments are supposed to be used in? I don't really anticipate having both fragments displayed in a single screen (e.g. on a tablet), but I don't see how I can use one activity for each because of the limitations of the tabbed interface (when I created the activity in eclipse, I was prompted to select what kind of layout, I chose tabbed layout, and automatically code for fragments within an activity corresponding to several tabs was generated)

Can anyone help? Should "take photo" and "view photos" be fragments or activities?

Comment: I think this is why the Fragments were created so that you can have multiple fragments with their own lifecycle in a single activity.

Comment: @KL please accept the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should definitely be fragments.

This does in no way contradict anything, plus I do not understand your concern about showing both fragments in a single screen. If you do not want that to happen, you just program accordingly. That is certainly not something that just happens because of the choices that you have mentioned so far.

Answer (score 1):

**Fragments** is the best method you can use for the purpose you mentioned above. You can check the below links to know about the usage of fragments.

[Creating a fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[android fragments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm)

[android fragments tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)